# What does Passport.js use the client_id and client_secret for?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I'm implementing the OAuth2 resource owner password credentials grant with Passport.js and the oauth2-client-password strategy for an API, but I'm confused as to what the client_id and client_scret are supposed to be? The [specs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3) for the resource owner password credentials grant say:

> The client makes a request to the token endpoint by adding the
> following parameters using the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
> format per Appendix B with a character encoding of UTF-8 in the HTTP
> request entity-body:

> grant_type

> ```
>     REQUIRED.  Value MUST be set to "password".
> ```

> username

> ```
>     REQUIRED.  The resource owner username.
> ```

> password

> ```
>     REQUIRED.  The resource owner password.
> ```

> scope

> ```
>     OPTIONAL.  The scope of the access request as described by
> ```

```
     Section 3.3.
```

But the Passport.js strategy is documented to be used like this:

```
passport.use(new ClientPasswordStrategy(
  function(clientId, clientSecret, done) {
    Clients.findOne({ clientId: clientId }, function (err, client) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!client) { return done(null, false); }
      if (client.clientSecret != clientSecret) { return done(null, false); }
      return done(null, client);
    });
  }
));
```

So my question is, if the specs don't say anything about the client_id or client_secret being required, why is the oauth2-client-password strategy using the client_id and secret_id?

Comment: Glen, did you ever work this out? I'm wondering the same thing right now. The spec doesn't require client_id or client_secret, so I'm wondering why the strategy does.

Comment: To be honest, I can't quite remember the basis for question anymore. As I look at it now, clientId and clientSecret are just arbitrary parameter names that could just have easily been username & password instead. With all the many passport modules, I wouldn't be surprised if there was some copying/pasting which might account for why the callback parameters have rather odd names. Does that help, or am I completely missing the point? (Sorry if I am, it's been a while since I was reading all about auth and Passportjs)

Comment: They *seem* to be arbitrary, but the strategy actually checks the body for presence of both the clientId and clientSecret. In any case, I was able to work this out. Still confused as to the presence of those checks, though.

Comment: While researching the same thing I found a nice code example (Node.js) the provides a working model that may be helpful - http://aleksandrov.ws/2013/09/12/restful-api-with-nodejs-plus-mongodb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing by now you have this but thought i would add an answer anyway.

- ClientId is your id to match against your database
- ClientSecret is the password that you will compare against the hash or encrypted password in your database.

Sample Code:

```
    Client.verify = function(clientId, secret, next){

    this.getByClientId(clientId, function(err, client){

    if(err) {
        return next(err);
    }

    if(!client){
        return next(null, false);
    }

    SecurityUtil.compare(secret, client.hash, function(err, result){

        if(err){
            return next(err);
        }

        next(null, result);

    });

    });

    };
```

Comment: Right. I can't remember quite why I was asking this question. It seems to make perfect sense now. But thanks for answering. If someone else gets stuck, this might be helpful.